# Maven + Запуск Плагинов

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Всем добрый день. Проект в eclipse. Необходимо запустить 2 плагина Maven`а. Первый собирает Jar-file , а второй выполняет cmd команду (для запаковки данного jar файла). Проблема в том, что в Pom.xml пишу последовательно 2 плагина и при запуске ,первый отрабатывает нормально, а второй (походу запускается, когда первый еще не закончил работу и не запаковывает, пишет ошибку, что jar файл некорректен). 
Пробовал ставить разные Phase. Не помогло. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Из pom.xml

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
                <outputDirectory>C:\DELTA.HuaweiSPGPlugin\lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>runbatchfile</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <executable>servicebuilder</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-packPAR</argument>
                    <argument>.</argument>
                    <argument>DELTA.HuaweiSPGPlugin.par</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Выложите из pom.xml часть build > plugins с вашей конфигурацией.

Comment: <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
      
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
     <outputDirectory>C:\DELTA.HuaweiSPGPlugin\lib</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Comment: <plugin><groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4.0</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>runbatchfile</id>
<phase>install</phase>
<goals>
<goal>exec</goal>
</goals>
</execution></executions>
    <configuration>
     <executable>servicebuilder</executable>
     <arguments>
                            <argument>-packPAR</argument>
                            <argument>.</argument>
                         <argument>DELTA.HuaweiSPGPlugin.par</argument>
                        </arguments>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: Предполагаю, что у Вас в проекте не существует файла servicebuilder, который запускается через plug-in exec-maven-plugin.

Будет больше информации, будут другие версии.

Comment: servicebuilder - это exe файл , который находится в переменной path. 
Суть вопроса это как сделать , чтобы первый плагин полностью отработал и далее запустился второй. 
servicebuilder - cmd команда